# How to apply z-index to a content of div to display in above pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created one table and to the last column of the table, I have added pseudo elements. That last column contains an image. That image is getting clipped due to pseudo elements. I tried adding z-index to that image, but it's not working. HTML code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td><img src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/22/05/05/160_F_122050525_sPpYBGxcms3Wpz6tJNnv23Xq7dq60RXi.jpg' height='25'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
     <td><img src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/22/05/05/160_F_122050525_sPpYBGxcms3Wpz6tJNnv23Xq7dq60RXi.jpg' height='25'></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
     <td><img src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/22/05/05/160_F_122050525_sPpYBGxcms3Wpz6tJNnv23Xq7dq60RXi.jpg' height='25'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS code:

```
td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I have regenerated the issue in following pluker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oTGWJrAFk5esgnwTOvKE?p=preview

How to avoid an image from getting clipped?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1st: this a css issue so no need to tag jquery , javascript .. 2nd: add `position : relative` to your image while changing`z-index`

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/qxP6jEELjVnCMzFzaMSR?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: relative; z-index: 2` on the image to stack on top of the pseudo element, which is `z-index: 1`. You could also remove the `z-index` from the pseudo element, and just add `position: relative` to the `img`, if the `z-index` on the pseudo element isn't necessary for some other reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    td:nth-child(3):before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    }
    td img { position: relative; z-index: 2;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td><img src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/22/05/05/160_F_122050525_sPpYBGxcms3Wpz6tJNnv23Xq7dq60RXi.jpg' height='25'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td><img src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/22/05/05/160_F_122050525_sPpYBGxcms3Wpz6tJNnv23Xq7dq60RXi.jpg' height='25'></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
         <td><img src='https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/22/05/05/160_F_122050525_sPpYBGxcms3Wpz6tJNnv23Xq7dq60RXi.jpg' height='25'></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following css just by removing z-index

```
td:nth-child(3)::before {
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: unset; //use either unset or relative
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will just solve your issue
Thanks,